# How to center some star signs

Tags: horizontal-alignment

In the text environment, I want to centering some stars between paragraphs. I know I can do this by

```
 \begin{center}
    \color{cyan}\makebox[5cm]{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}
 \end{center}
```

but the vertical space is hard to control. I do not know why the following does not work

```
$\centering{\color{cyan}\makebox[5cm]{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}}$
```

The result will not in the center.

Comment: `\centering{$\color{cyan}\makebox[5cm]{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}$}` does it for me... note that `$` structurally is an environmentlike structure where a lot of macros don't work...

Comment: why not for me ?

Comment: did you put the `\centering` outside of the `$`? If that still does not work you should provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) and tell us which latex you use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{$\color{cyan}\makebox[5cm]{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}$}

nice
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\centering` does not take an argument, this will center the rest of the document.

Comment: eventualy `\centerline{$\color{cyan} ....$}`

Comment: @TeXnician oups - sorry. fixed.

Comment: Thanks, friends. Zarko and AndiW . Your codes both work!

Comment: You're definitely short a `\noindent`. Also, there seems to be no need for the internal `\makebox` or switches to math mode...

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\cstars}{\vskip 1.2ex\noindent\par\makebox[\linewidth]{\color{cyan}* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}\par}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\cstars
\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No need to use `[1][20]` - it's not used in the definition of `\cstars`

Comment: That's. I guess I copied an initial version with the number of stars as an optional argument, then decided it was unnecessary, and forgot to remove the arguments. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: :) you're welcome...

Answer (score 1):

A simple centred paragraph:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\stars}{%
  \par
  \nobreak
  {\centering\color{cyan}\raisebox{-.7ex}[0pt][0pt]{* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *}\par}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\stars

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```